# HTML form (method = "post") won't submit

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form with three inputs: **Make**, **Year**, **Mileage**.
The conditions are that **Make** should not be empty, and **Year** and **Mileage** must be numeric.
The form submits when the conditions are met.

However, when one of the conditions is not met, I'm using PHP to redirect to the same page and display an error message on the screen. Now when I enter correct values, the form wouldn't submit. Nor does the cancel button redirects it to the previous page.

If I want the form to submit after the error message has been displayed, I have to refresh it and then enter correct values. **How can I avoid the refresh?**

**Here's the code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "pdo.php";

if (!isset($_SESSION['email']) || strlen($_SESSION['email']) < 1) {
    die('Not logged in');
}

if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
    header("Location: view.php");
    return;
}

if (isset($_POST['make']) && isset($_POST['year']) && isset($_POST['mileage'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['make']) < 1) {
        $_SESSION['failure'] = "Make is required";
        header("Location: add.php");
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (!is_numeric($_POST['year']) || !is_numeric($_POST['mileage'])) {
            $_SESSION['failure'] = "Mileage and year must be numeric";
            header("Location: add.php");
            return;
        }
        else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO autos(make, year, mileage)
                    VALUES(:mk, :yr, :ml)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':mk' => $_POST['make'],
                ':yr' => $_POST['year'],
                ':ml' => $_POST['mileage']  
            ));
            $_SESSION["record"] = "Record inserted";
            header("Location: view.php");
            return;
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mohammed Misran's Automobile Tracker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tracking Autos for <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['email']);?></h1>
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['failure'])) {
            echo '<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION['failure'])."</p\n";
            unset($_SESSION['failure']);
        }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <p>Make:
        <input type="text" name="make" size="40"/></p>
        <p>Year:
        <input type="text" name="year" size="40"/></p>
        <p>Mileage:
        <input type="text" name="mileage" size="40"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Add"/>
        <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really need an `exit;` after a `header('Location:....');` and not a `return` As `return` is used to jump back from a function call which you do not appear to be in

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the form wouldn't submit"? Do you have javascript code which prevents the form submit? What do you see in the "network tab" of your browser to see the requests you are sending? Do you see any request being added when you press the "Add" button?

Comment: @Progman There's no javascript involved. The browser doesn't request anything when I press the "Add" button.

Comment: @MohammedMisran You have a typo at `"</p\n"`, there is a `>` missing.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I replaced all the ```return;``` with ```exit;```. It's still the same problem

Comment: @Progman my bad. that was the issue why it wasn't submitting. thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Good Afternoon,
I think its better to use HTML form properties, you want to validate the entered values, so its easy to do it like this:
1- 'Make' should not be empty:

```
  <input type="text" name="make" size="40" required/>
```

2- 'Year' and 'Mileage' must be numeric:

```
  <input type="number" name="year" size="40"/>
  <input type="number" name="mileage" size="40"/>
```

by this way you dont need to write any php validation for your form, if you want to use php validation let me know to guide you for solving your problem

Comment: He does not need PHP/backend validation, if he has it validated in his HTML? REALLY? .......

Comment: That is exactly what  I was trying to imply with my comment...oh, the absurdity..

Answer (score -1):

when Submit button press then first you have to Check Submit Button Post like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   //Your Code Logic...
}
```

then get data from POST & store it in variable like this... for Your Reference

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
}
```

in html...

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter username"><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="enter password"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

then store in database like this

```
$sql="insert into user(username, password) 
 values('$username','$password')";
```

Comment: 1. OP Cannot check `$_POST['submit'])` because that button does not have a name attribute and **Big 2.** Converting a perfectly and more inportantly **secure** PDO query into a **insecure** concatenated query is NOT a step forward :) and 3. moving data out of a perfectly good array into an unnecessary scalar variable achieves nothing but wasted CPU cycles and memory